# How to make a jlabel resizable according to the window

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jlabel

I am using netbeans to design a JFrame. 
[image]

now when i compile and run.It executes and opens a window [image]

now the problem is when i maximixe the window..I want the image or Jlabel to cover the width of the jframe. [image]

SO how can i do it.Plz Help

Answer (score 4):

First stop using visual designer. Stop now. Immediately. Forget that it exists. Visual designers create non-maintainable code. They save 5 minutes at the beginning and cause you to spend hours later.

Now, take a look on any java layouts tutorial. For example this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Once you read and understood it go back to your application. Think what layout(s) you need. Design the application. Implement it. If you still have problem that you cannot solve yourself within reasonable time ask more specific question again.

When you understand layouts good enough and want to implement real application with a lot of dialogs take a look on [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: thanx for the suggestion.. I was thinking to do the same but due to lack of time.I thought of using visual designer. But you are right i ll do it manually now.

Comment: Using layouts is always a good idea, but it doesn't solve the problem. An Image doesn't automatically scale no matter what layout manager you use.

Comment: @camickr, you are right. However OP should first learn some basics of the GUI programming with java, then start solving his problem. Probably he does not need label at all. There are many ways to show and stretch image using java.

Answer (score 3):

A JLabel always paints the Icon at it actual size.

If you want dynamic scaling of the image then you need to do custom painting. Basically you would override the paintComponent(..) method of a JComponent with code like:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
```

Of course you would need to pass the image as a parameter when you create the class. It also assumes you add the component directly to the content pane which uses a BorderLayout by default.

For fancier or more flexible solutions you could:

1. Use the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/)
2. Use [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) on a JLabel

Comment: I am not good with swings .So i was using visual designer.Thanx for the code.I will use it after studying the swings and then i ll let you know if problem exists..Thanx

Comment: Beg your pardon, but why would the `ImageObserver` part be `null`, instead of referring to the current `JComponent` on which the image is being drawn ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw, You only need "this" if the image has not been completely read into memory at the time the paintComponent() method is invoked. Changed the example so it will work in all situations.